# Role Provider error in web.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, web-config, roleprovider

My application is in **Asp.Net MVC3**, my application was running perfectly but all of a sudden i'm getting an error in my **Web.Config** in  my role manager tag.

Below is my **RoleManager** tag of **web.config**

```
<roleManager defaultProvider="MASSIARoleProvider" enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="true">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="MASSIARoleProvider" type="MASSIA.Helpers.MASSIARoleProvider, MASSIA" connectionStringName="MASSIAEntities" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
```

**Below is the error i'm getting directly when i run my application:**

**[updated Error Image]**
[image]

I have a file **MASSIARoleProvider.cs** in my solution in the directory Helper.

**Below is Heirarchy of my RoleProvider file.**

**--> Massia --> Helpers --> MASSIARoleProvider.cs**

My solution was executing perfectly but i'm getting this error all of a sudden.

Comment: In the YSOD, you haven't specified an assembly name as you did in your code snippet: `type="MASSIA.Helpers.MASSIARoleProvider, MASSIA"`.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, please check, i have updated my question with the latest error image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<roleManager defaultProvider="MASSIARoleProvider" enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="true">
        <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="MASSIARoleProvider" type="MASSIA.Helpers.MASSIARoleProvider" connectionStringName="MASSIAEntities" />
        </providers>
        </roleManager>
```

**Attemp 2:**

Check for your MASSIARoleProvider file and see whether the Solution name and references used are perfectly correct.

**Attempt 3:**

**The last and least recommended.**

Create a new solution, if and only if your solution is in the **beginning stage** and try to reconfigure the **RoleProvider**. Once it solved the issue for me, I made a new solution, added the existing files to the news solution and executed the new solution and it executed perfectly. I did not made any change to the code, i just included the existing files from the old solution to the new one.